# Why are there few votes?

Tags: discussion, votes

I don't know if it's only my impression, but I think that people don't vote.

---

**Edit**: An interesting article about votes: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Comment: It is just your impression. I vote obsessively, but I am very picky with what I vote for. In opinion answers, I must agree. In Electrical answers, I must consider it correct.

Comment: But you're a "heavy user" here. And the rest? We have 1354 users and 2931 visitors/day. The most voted question has only 32 up votes with 1k views. I think there are few votes. But I'm still a beginner and would like to understand whether it is how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Just some notes on how *important* active participation (including voting) is on every site.

#### Voting is a Critical Part of Participation

Posting questions and answers is only *half* of the equation. Voting is what provides the vetting (examination and evaluation) of the answers on this site. Without it, there's no expertise; just random thought that may or may not be correct.

#### Voting is the Basis of Community Self-Policing

Without voting, you will not have users with enough reputation to keep the site running smoothly. Without editors (+2000 rep users), the on-going quality of the posts will suffer. Without closers (+3000 rep users), the site is always in danger of succumbing to spam and declining quality.

### Soon, Voting May Be *Critical* to Getting out of Beta (Graduation)

Beta sites operate under *reduced* reputation requirements. When a site graduates from beta, the privilege levels return to their *normal*  levels:

```
   15     Vote up
   15     Flag offensive
   50     Leave comments†
  100     Edit community wiki posts
  125     Vote down (costs 1 rep)
  150     Create new tags
  200     Reduced advertising
  200     Retag questions
  250     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
 1000     Show total up and down vote counts
 2000     Edit other people's posts
 3000     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
10000     Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
```

Under represented sites (with low-rep users) will struggle when the site graduates.

**We are seriously considering basing the graduation requirements on having enough 2000- and 3000-rep users to sustain the site**, and not a hard 90-day limit.

If a site cannot take care of themselves, they are *not* ready for graduation. If they reach that point *before* 90 days, they should be able to move on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Robert. Now I know that my preocupation is not in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting observation. Is it in fact a fact, though? Curious mind could extract number of votes of each user, normalize it somehow (divide by activity for example) and compare to other exchange sites. I see in my imagination so many beautiful graphs as a results of such exercise :). Until that what is left is speculation and anecdotal evidences. (I do not have idea how to do it, but since there are stack exchange database dumps somebody with good scripting skills could do it)

Comment: I have seen similar voting patterns, O Engenheiro has a habit of asking questions that do not get many up-votes.

Comment: It's not only me. It's a pattern. I take the newest 50 questions and there is an average. And this average is not different from mine.

Comment: Check out http://odata.stackexchange.com/ - I don't think they have the data dump of this site, though.

Answer (score 1):

Pages which have multiple commenters and active threads of discussion seem to attract more interest and more voting.