# When will the data dump for E&R (and other beta sites) be made available?

Tags: support, data-dump, data-explorer

The data dumps of Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, their meta sites, and Web Applications are available for analysis on http://odata.stackexchange.com/.  According to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/creative-commons-data-dump-oct-10/), Stack Apps should be available as well, but I don't see it there.

Looking at http://stackexchange.com/sites, there are a number of other pages which have the same status as Web Applications and Stack Apps.  E&R is still in beta, but isn't all that far behind (especially because it was seeded with content from Chiphacker).

I'd like to have access to the data dump through [odata.stackexchange.com](http://odata.stackexchange.com) to help answer questions [like this one](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/why-are-there-few-votes/84#84).  What's the timeline for this operation?

Answer (score 4):

Our data-dump will not be available until the site graduates.

> [We generally wait 4-6 months until a
>   site has enough data to be useful.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/creative-commons-data-dump-jul-10/#comment-48221)

Robert took the time to give us a bit more information. To quote him,

> Scheduling the creation of the data
>   dumps isn't just a matter of the
>   usefulness of the data. There are only
>   finite resources to getting these
>   sites launched. It takes significantly
>   more resources to launch these sites
>   out of beta than creating them in the
>   first place. Creating the data dumps
>   happens on a schedule which is spread
>   out across the entire network. I'm
>   sure everyone would like to jump ahead
>   and have their sites' data now. But
>   unless there is a really pressing
>   reason for Electronics.SE to jump
>   ahead, the data dumps will be
>   available when they are ready.
>   Patience. They're coming.

Comment: You're a mod.  This *is* the post that states this :)

Comment: Found it! It's [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/creative-commons-data-dump-jul-10/#comment-48221), on the [cc-wiki-dump blog topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/): Jeff Attwood♦ said, on 6/4/10, "Why would [Stack Apps] be [included in the data dump]? We generally wait 4-6 months until a site has enough data to be useful."

Comment: I think that E&R has enough data to be useful (Chiphacker's been around for a while), and analysis is not just for trends.  If anything, beta sites should have more frequent data dumps, so that we can quantify and respond to unwanted behavior.

Comment: Thanks for finding that, myself and another moderator could not find it. I will send the admins a message on your note.

Comment: Scheduling the creation of the data dumps isn't just a matter of the usefulness of the data. There are only finite resources to getting these sites launched. It takes significantly more resources to launch these sites out of beta than creating them in the first place. Creating the data dumps happens on a schedule which is spread out across the entire network. I'm sure everyone would like to jump ahead and have their sites' data now. But unless there is a *really* pressing reason for Electronics.SE to jump ahead, the data dumps will be available when they are ready. Patience. They're coming.

Comment: I had a feeling that it would take too much work, thank you for taking the time to answer that Robert.